# Print Uniqe line

Tags: bash, awk

I Have log file like the following, I need to print only unique one from this log.

```
 3185 ms: server-session 192.168.32.9 /db/data/transaction/commit
 1778 ms: server-session 192.168.32.9 /db/data/transaction/commit
 1770 ms: server-session 192.168.32.9 /db/data/transaction/commit
 1731 ms: server-session 192.168.32.9 /db/data/transaction/commit
 1730 ms: server-session 192.168.32.9 /db/data/transaction/commit
 1729 ms: server-session 192.168.32.9 /db/data/transaction/commit
```

for  eg:  from this log i need to print only following line which took more time to execute.

```
 3185 ms: server-session 192.168.32.9 /db/data/transaction/commit
```

I really appreciate if anyone can suggest me a solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print for every ip the record with the highest first field (the number before the ms), use:

```
$ awk 'a[$4]<$1 {a[$4]=$1;b[$4]=$0} END{for(i in a) print b[i]}' test
2115 ms: server-session 192.168.33.9 /db/data/transaction/commit
3185 ms: server-session 192.168.32.9 /db/data/transaction/commit
3145 ms: server-session 192.168.32.10 /db/data/transaction/commit
```

Explained:

```
a[$4]<$1 {         # if the new first field value is more than previous 
    a[$4]=$1       # store the first field
    b[$4]=$0       # store the whole record with the highest first field
} 
END {              # in the end
    for(i in a)    # go thru every stored value
        print b[i] # and print them
}
```

I used as `test`:

```
$ cat > test
3185 ms: server-session 192.168.32.9 /db/data/transaction/commit
1778 ms: server-session 192.168.32.9 /db/data/transaction/commit
1770 ms: server-session 192.168.32.9 /db/data/transaction/commit
1731 ms: server-session 192.168.32.9 /db/data/transaction/commit
1730 ms: server-session 192.168.32.9 /db/data/transaction/commit
1729 ms: server-session 192.168.32.9 /db/data/transaction/commit
3185 ms: server-session 192.168.32.9 /db/data/transaction/commit
3145 ms: server-session 192.168.32.10 /db/data/transaction/commit
2115 ms: server-session 192.168.33.9 /db/data/transaction/commit
```

Comment: Thanks James, this is really help full

Comment: @James Brown:- Please have some courtesy to point out what is wrong/missing with the already accepted answer rather than painlessly reading through the comments from the author from the accepted solution and posting an answer of your own.

Comment: @James Brown: Whatever you have posted as an answer is not even part of the author's question description. So assuming I delete my answer and the comments with it, your answer will seem meaningless.

Comment: @inian: I'm sorry you feel that way about me posting to help the community that has helped me a lot in my work and hobby. I browsed thru latest questions and reading OPs question and example noticed that there was only 1 ip in the example which kind of like made no sense and wrote a solution supporting more than one ip. After testing it with mock data (`123 foo`) I read your solution and others' and found more example data in the comments and tested my solution out and decided to post it because some people really can't write out the question and if that was really what OP wanted, [continued]

Comment: ... maybe the next person after him would find my solution helpful. I really can't rewrite your already accepted answer now could I? And I really am not going to be the guy telling you in the still already accepted answer's comment how you should've coded it. Well, again I am sorry I brought my view to the problem out if I hurt peoples' feelings by doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this-

```
sort -nk 1  file.txt | tail -1
```

Sorts according to the first column and picks up the last line (which is the one with the most time).

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution using `awk`, using `sort`, `uniq` for this seems to be an over-kill.

```
awk -v max=0 '{if($1>max){line=$0; max=$1}}END{print line}' file
3185 ms: server-session 192.168.32.9 /db/data/transaction/commit
```

Comment: Its worked fine, How about  if i have 100s of lines with different lines  Like 3185 ms: server-session 192.168.32.9 /db/data/transaction/commit   and  3145 ms: server-session 192.168.32.10 /db/data/transaction/commit and 2115 ms: server-session 192.168.33.9 /db/data/transaction/commit

Comment: @Renjith: it will work for as many lines as need, as long as you have the time value in column 1

Comment: I have question for you.. is there any way  to print the unique line if i have different lines, On my question i have all lines are same except time, how to print if i have different lines

Comment: @Renjith: If you had understood my answer correctly, contents of the line except the "time" field doesn't matter. The solution works plainly on the column 1 time value and picks the largest among the lines and prints the entire line(see `line=$0`), what the line contains is irrelevant. Hope that clarifies your question.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, My question really is, what if i have different content on each line. and i want to print the unique one ? assume on my question i have two different ip 192.168.32.9 and 192.168.32.10 and i want to print both

Comment: Not sure, what you are requesting, but from the above log file, if you have entries with a new IP and want unique IP lines, you can use `awk '!seen[$4]++' file`, which will show only lines with unique IP addresses

Comment: @Renjith: I specifically answered to your new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39249736/print-only-unique-lines, in the above comments as `awk '!seen[$4]++' file` and you seem to ignore it and accept some other answer as an accepted solution? why?

Comment: Sorry, I thought i can select both ans, and i didnt knew that it will remove the one i previously marked. So Sorry..

Answer (score 0):

Try `uniq` with its `-s` option:

```
uniq -s 5 file
```